# Xamarin.Android - can't add "android:exported" flag

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.android

I can't publish my app to Google Play. It says I need to add "android:exported" flag. The problem is with this code (AndroidManifest.xml) from obj folder, Package Com.OneSignal 3.2.0:

```
    <!--Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
    <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I copied this code to my Properties/AndroidManifest.xml and add "android:exported" flag.

```
    <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The point is that after build these entries are duplicated in AndroidManifest.xml in obj folder. One is with android:exported="false" and one without android:exported="false". If I remove android:exported="false" flag in Properties/AndroidManifest.xml then there is no duplication.

I don't want to update oneSignal to version 4 at the moment but I can't find any solution to my problem. A few weeks ago I had the same problem with another app (but it was build with Visual Studio for Mac, not Windows) and I didn't end up with duplicated entries.

Answer (score 0):

From document [Safer component exporting](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported), we could find that:

> If your app targets Android 12 or higher and contains activities,
> services, or broadcast receivers that use intent filters, you must
> explicitly declare the android:exported attribute for these app
> components.

and we can notice the warning as follows:

> Warning: If an activity, service, or broadcast receiver uses intent
> filters and doesn't have an `explicitly-declared` value for
> `android:exported`, your app can't be installed on a device that runs
> Android 12 or higher.

So, you need to recheck if you have added `android:exported="true"` or `"android:exported="false"` to all `receivers`, `services`, and `activity` tags (e.g. `BootUpReceiver` and `UpgradeReceiver`).

For example:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
public class SampleReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // Do stuff here.

    }
}
```

**Note:**

From document [Working with the Android Manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-manifest), we find that:

> Xamarin.Android helps to minimize this difficulty by allowing you to
> add custom attributes to your classes, which will then be used to
> automatically generate the manifest for you. Our goal is that 99% of
> our users should never need to manually modify `AndroidManifest.xml`.

So, we generally don't manually add code to file `AndroidManifest.xml`. This can easily lead to the problem of duplicate attributes as you said a.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You wrote: "So, you need to recheck if you have added android:exported="true" or "android:exported="false" to all receivers, services, and activity tags (e.g. BootUpReceiver and UpgradeReceiver)". The problem is that BootUpReceiver and UpgradeReceiver come from third party package Com.OneSignal. This is not my code so how can I add exported flag to it?."

Comment: From [nuget Com.OneSignal](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Com.OneSignal/),we could find that this package has been deprecated. The suggested Alternatives is
[OneSignalSDK.Xamarin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OneSignalSDK.Xamarin/).

Comment: Yes, I know it is deprecated, but I have no time to move to OneSignalSDK.Xamarin now. I have to target API 31 before 31 August.

Comment: The  `Com.OneSignal` nuget has been deprecated and generally not maintained. If you don't update to the new NuGet, your app may have various problems.

Comment: Jessie, thanks in interested in my issue. Yes, I will update this package soon. For the time being this is how I "solved" the problem: I created a app file ("android:exported="false" not present). I downloaded Apk Editor Studio and edited Manifest file to meet requirements